# Focus of the input not going out by code

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, input

I have an application of `PhoneGap` 2.2.0 and `Android` 4.0.4.

When I press the input I opened div above it.

My input and My Div:

```
  <input type="text" onclick="OpenDiv();" id="MyInput" />

    <div id="MyDiv">
       ...
    </div>
```

css:

```
#MyDiv
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5000;
    display: none;
}
```

OpenDiv function:

```
function OpenSearch() {
    $('#MyDiv').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Older versions **no problem**, in this version the focus from the first input does not pass, and a red square was created over my div.

I tried to take the focus away, as follows:

```
$('#MyInput').blur();
```

And also I tried to hide Android keyboard at the time that the div opens:

```
//It works for me in this application on other things
 window.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard.hide(function () {
    }, function () {
    });
```

**Nothing helped ..**

Red square still remains above My div,

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opened the div I **hid** the input, then the focus came out.

It's pretty serious bug that it **the only way the focus goes from the input**,

But it's the **only** solution that worked for me.

Here the code:

```
function OpenSearch() {
    $('#MyInput').css('display', 'none');
    $('#MyDiv').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `document.activeElement.blur();`